# Amino acid usage vs Amino acid Identity

Tags: bioinformatics, genome

I have a little confusion regarding the terms "amino acid usage" and "amino acid identity". 
How can amino acid usage be calculated? I heard about "CodonW". Is there any other option do we have?

Secondly, Can we use amino acid usage for building a phylogenetic relationship as we perform in amino acid identity?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Typically, we do not provide recommendations for software as that can be heavily opinionated.

Comment: This question is a better fit for https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/ or https://biology.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

**Amino acid usage**, or codon usage/bias, refers to the comparison of the **frequency** of amino acids present in one or more protein sequences across one or more organisms. The position of the amino acids in the protein sequence is **not** considered. For more information see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codon_usage_bias

**Amino acid identity**, or protein sequence alignment, is the **comparison** of amino acids between two or more sequences, usually obtained via biological sequence alignment. Comparisons are made only between amino acids that are estimated to be related, eg. by common ancestor. See:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_alignment

ExPASY is a nice website to search for tool that do one or both of these tasks:

https://www.expasy.org/